# Excel VBA macro to copy rows that meet a criteria to a new row on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops, paste

I am struggling with my code- and will admit that I am a newbie to VBA. 
Yes- I have reviewed a ton of posts and dont seem to be able to fix my code!

I am trying to extract rows that meet a specific value ('Priority')- which is located in column H across 15 sheets. The code needs to extract any rows that meet the criteria from all of the 15 sheets. The extracted row is to be pasted into the front sheet "FootpathStrategyTool"- starting at cell A20 (below the predefined headers).
I am having difficulty getting the loop to paste the copied row into the next blank row. The code runs, but seems to miss the first few worksheets. It may have something to do with my final row line. 
If anyone can help I would be extremely grateful!!!!

```
Sub getdata()
    '1. what is the priority value you wish to search for?
    '2. define lastrow for the sheets
    '3. Find records that match priority value and paste them into the main sheet

Dim Priority As Integer
Dim Worksheet As Worksheet

Priority = Sheets("FootpathStrategyTool").Range("I10").Value

' Find the final row of data for all sheets

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Worksheet.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim NextRow As Range
Set NextRow = Sheets("FootpathStrategyTool").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 
1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

' Loop through each row
For x = 4 To finalrow
    ' Decide if to copy based on column H Priority
    ThisValue = Cells(x, 8).Value
    If ThisValue = Priority Then
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
        Sheets("FootpathStrategyTool").Select
        NextRow = Cells(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 19
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select

    End If
    ' Step down 1 row from present location.
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("FootpathStrategyTool").Select
 Next x

Next Worksheet


End Sub
```

Comment: maybe just a typo here... but `“A”` is NOT the same as `"A"`

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the pickup- it is indeed a typo, but it only made more mess!

Comment: why is the "paste" part outside of the "if"? wouldn't that paste lines which match over and over for each line which does not match after them?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions I hope you find helpful:

1. `Dim Worksheet As Worksheet`. Typically you wouldn't want to declare a variable name with the same name as an object. It can make things a bit confusing. I'd suggest `Dim wsData As Worksheet`.
2. `ThisValue = Cells(x, 8).Value`. While this works, you haven't explicitly declared ThisValue with a type which means ThisValue is now a Variant type. In the example above, you have a simple evaluation of "`If ThisValue = Priority Then`" so everything in this code will probably work as expected, but you might get unexpected results or errors in a more complex application. The same goes for "finalrow" and "x".
3. There 's a significant difference between "Cells" and ".Cells". ".Cells" refers to a specific worksheet that you defined earlier in the code while "Cells" refers to whichever worksheet was last active. Since your code is trying to create row numbers while jumping back and forth between the front sheet and the data sheets, it's easy to lose track of which sheet you're actually creating the numbers from.
4. When referring to specific worksheets and ranges, it's not always necessary to jump between them and activate them. You can just move the data as an array by specifying the source and destination locations.
5. I believe, however, the source of your problem is
   `NextRow = Cells(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 19`. You established the last row range when you Declared and Set it above, and now your re-establishing it then adding another 19 rows to it. Also, `Cells(“A” & Rows.Count)` is not a valid reference. "A" will return as empty which means you're actually saying Cells(Rows.Count) and not providing a column reference.

Please consider this as an alternative.

```
Sub getdata()
    '1. what is the priority value you wish to search for?
    '2. define lastrow for the sheets
    '3. Find records that match priority value and paste them into the main sheet

'This identifies precisely which sheet you're copying data to.
Dim wsHome As Worksheet: Set wsHome = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FootpathStrategyTool")
Dim Priority As Integer: Priority = wsHome.Range("I10").Value
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim ThisValue As Variant
Dim NextRow As Variant
Dim finalrow As Long

'i0 will be used to cycle through the data worksheets.
Dim i0 As Long
'i1 will be used to increment through the rows on the Home sheet starting at row 20.
Dim i1 As Long: i1 = 20

'This says to start at the second worksheet and look at each one to the end.
For i0 = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    'This specifies exactly which worksheet you're working with.
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i0)
        finalrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Loop through each row
        For x = 4 To finalrow
            'Decide if to copy based on column H Priority. Pull the whole range as an object.
            If .Cells(x, 8).Value = Priority Then
                ThisValue = .Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, 33)).Value
                'Identify the data's destination on the Home tab.
                Set NextRow = wsHome.Cells(i1, 1)
                'Resize the destination range and drop the data in one line.
                NextRow.Resize(1, UBound(ThisValue, 2)).Value = ThisValue
                'Increment the cell reference to the next row.
                i1 = i1 + 1
            End If
        Next x
    End With
Next i0
End Sub
```